# Removing /home url

Tags: uri

A little tricky this one --- I got handed this site and they have somehow messed
the theming up on the home page, so they recreated a new home and redirected it 
there - both in the config section and in the .htacess
but - - - they dont want the url ../home to appear

Is there a quick fix?

---- update
Thanx but no luck still - I am now certain its an htacess issue. I have the following settings.

- RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain.net [NC]
- RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ Rewriterule ^(.*)$
- http://mydomain.net/home [L,R=301]

What I want to do is to remove the /home
If I delete the /home I get a page with no themeing

Comment: Perhaps [global redirect](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) can help you out

Answer (score 4):

Navigate to /admin/config/system/site-information, and set "Default front page" to the path you want, without a leading slash (sounds like "home" in this case).

Then remove the redirect from htaccess.

Comment: thanx, tried that but no luck - I'm fairly certain it has to do with the 3 lines I bullet-ed in the update

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with the [Front Page](http://drupal.org/project/front) module.

> The Front Page module allows for customised home pages dependant on role. The pages can be of the following types:
>
> - **Alias** - Allows for another Drupal path to be shown as the home page without redirecting the user.
> - **Redirect** - Allows you to redirect users to a local or remote URL.
> - **Themed** - Allows you to enter some static text that will be placed into the content area of a standard Drupal page.
> - **Full** - Allows for static content to be displayed to the screen as is. This method does not pass through Drupal's theming system.

Comment: I have always felt that this module is an over kill for a smaller problem.

Comment: I liked the front page module but it did not solve the issue, however it did clarify for me that the issue is actually not really a drupal issue but more a server or htacess issue